# Linux Kernel - Red/Black Trees

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, red-black-tree

I'm trying to implement a red/black tree in Linux per task_struct using code from `linux/rbtree.h`. I can get a red/black tree inserting properly in a standalone space in the kernel such as a module but when I try to get the same code to function with the `rb_root` declared in either `task_struct` or `task_struct->files_struct`, I get a `SEGFAULT` everytime I try an insert.

Here's some code:

In task_struct I create a `rb_root` struct for my tree (not a pointer). 
In `init_task.h`, macro `INIT_TASK(tsk)`, I set this equal to `RB_ROOT`. 
To do an insert, I use this code:

```cpp
rb_insert(&(current->fd_tree), &rbnode);
```

This is where the issue occurs.

My insert command is the standard insert that is documented in all RBTree documentation for the kernel:

```cpp
  int my_insert(struct rb_root *root, struct mytype *data)
  {
    struct rb_node **new = &(root->rb_node), *parent = NULL;

    /* Figure out where to put new node */
    while (*new) {
        struct mytype *this = container_of(*new, struct mytype, node);
        int result = strcmp(data->keystring, this->keystring);

        parent = *new;
        if (result < 0)
            new = &((*new)->rb_left);
        else if (result > 0)
            new = &((*new)->rb_right);
        else
            return FALSE;
    }

    /* Add new node and rebalance tree. */
    rb_link_node(&data->node, parent, new);
    rb_insert_color(&data->node, root);

    return TRUE;
  }
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Some reason this would work fine if I made a tree root outside of `task_struct`? If I make `rb_root` inside of a module this insert works fine. But once I put the actual tree root in the `task_struct` or even in the `task_struct->files_struct`, I get a `SEGFAULT`. Can a root node not be added in these structs?

Any tips are greatly appreciated. I've tried nearly everything I can think of.

---

**Edit:**

I get a `SEGFAULT` on the following line when trying to print and any line that accesses the tree. With this line you should get the understanding of how I'm handling the pointers. `rb_entry` and `rb_first` are methods already available in the kernel. `current` is a pointer to a task struct (current working process) and tree is my root node (not a pointer) which is a member of the task struct (I added). `rb_first` needs to pass a pointer `*rb_root`. I'm doing this wrong.

```cpp
printk(KERN_CRIT "node=%d\n", rb_entry(rb_first(&(current->tree)), struct rb_tree_struct, node)->fd_key);
```

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the way I'm adding a new node. I just do struct mytype __name__ to allocate space then add it using the insert above. do i need to use the malloc (or the kmalloc) or can I just allocate a new node like the way I'm doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the pointer values of root and/or data aren't what you expect? It might be useful to add

```
printk("%s: root=%p data=%p\n", __func__, root, data);
```

before the `while()` loop.

Comment: I get a SEGFAULT on the following line when trying to print and any line that accesses the tree. With this line you should get the understanding of how I'm handling the pointers. rb_entry and rb_first are methods already available in the kernel. current is a pointer to a task struct (current working process) and tree is my root node (not a pointer) which is a member of the task struct. rb_first needs to pass a pointer *rb_root. I'm doing this wrong. 
printk(KERN_CRIT "node=%d\n", rb_entry(rb_first(&(current->tree)), struct rb_tree_struct, node)->fd_key);